# Asymptotic simplification of $\frac{n-a-1\choose b-2}{n-1\choose b-1}$, where $a,b\ll n$.

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I am looking for an asymptotic (need not be) simplification of ${n-a-1\choose b-2}/{n-1\choose b-1}$, where $a,b\ll n$. Intuitively, I know that it should be of some form smaller than $b/n$ because ${n-2\choose b-2}/{n-1\choose b-1}\leq b/n$ (by expanding out the factorials and simplifying). How do I show this formally?

I have tried using the inequality
\begin{align*}
\Big(\frac{n}{k}\Big)^k\leq{n\choose k}\leq\Big(\frac{en}{k}\Big)^k,
\end{align*}
which did not seem to work very well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\binom{n-c}{d}\sim\frac{(n-c)^d}{d!}\sim\frac{n^d}{d!}$ to show your fraction is asymptotic to$$\frac{\tfrac{n^{b-2}}{(b-2)!}}{\tfrac{n^{b-1}}{(b-1)!}}=\frac{b-1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac{\binom{n-a-1}{b-2}}{\binom{n-1}{b-1}}\implies \log(a_n)=\log\left(\frac{\binom{n-a-1}{b-2}}{\binom{n-1}{b-1}} \right)$$ Write it in terms of factorials and use Stirling approximation to get
$$\log(a_n)=\log \left(\frac{(b-1) \Gamma (b-1)}{(b-2) \Gamma (b-2)}\right)+\log
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{2
   a+b-ab-1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Then the asymptotics
$$a_n \sim \frac{(b-1) \Gamma (b-1)}{(b-2) \Gamma (b-2)}\frac 1 n$$
$$\frac{(b-1) \Gamma (b-1)}{(b-2) \Gamma (b-2)}=b-1\implies a_n \sim \frac {  b-1 }n$$

You could go further to see $a$ and get
$$a_n \sim \frac {  b-1 }n\left(1+\frac{b-a (b-2)-1}{n} \right)$$